# ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes while deploying my app on Wildfly Server

Tags: java, rest, jboss, jersey, wildfly

i'm trying to make a simple rest service and deploy the app on wildfly server and when i try to deploy my app on server i have the following exception:

```
Cannot upload deployment: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => 
{"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./resttestapp" => 
"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service 
jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./resttestapp: 
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig 
instance does not contain any root resource classes. Caused by: 
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig 
instance does not contain any root resource classes."}}
```

I've tried a lot of thing from stackoverflow but nothing works for me.

I'm using Wildfly 9.0.2 (standalone, deploying via admin console), Intellij idea.

This is part of my pom.xml:

```
<groupId>cz.prg.rob</groupId>
  <artifactId>resttestapp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>resttestapp Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    <jersey.version>1.19.4</jersey.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-server -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
      <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.6</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

This is my web.xml:

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseyServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>cz.prg.rob</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JerseyServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is my service class:

```
package cz.prg.rob;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import java.util.Date;

@Path("/name")
public class UserService {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getName() {
        return "Qwerty";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/user")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public User getUser(@QueryParam("name") String name, @QueryParam("surname") String surname, @QueryParam("birthDate") Date birthDate) {
        return new User(name, surname, birthDate);
    }

}
```

and this is a part of my User (model) class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class User {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private Date birthDate;
}
```

This is my project structure:

[image: project structure]

I can't understand what i'm doing wrong. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that helped me:

I've added this as init param of JerseyServlet

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
  <param-value>cz.prg.rob.UserServiceApplication</param-value>
</init-param>
```

And this is the class where i've defined my resource class

```
public class UserServiceApplication extends Application {
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(UserService.class);
        return s;
    }
}
```

So looks like i have to say to jersey which classes are resource classes explicitly. If you want to add new resource classes just add them in HashSet into getClasses() method.